# Is there a way to add a case sensitive attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm working with jQuery to modify some svg <strike>files</strike> data on the fly... one of the things I need to do is modify the "viewBox" attribute.  When using jQuery as in the snippet below, however, it is doing a toLower() on the attribute so "viewBox" becomes "viewbox".  Normally I wouldn't care but this seems to break svg rendering (at least on Mac OS X in the finder and in Safari).

Is there a way to modify this natively in jQuery (via flag or something) or am I going to have to do a string replace afterwards?

```
var $svg = $('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"></svg>');
// do some work here
$svg.attr('viewBox', 0 + ' ' + 0 + ' ' + 288 + ' ' + 288);
```

Comment: This might not be what you are looking for, but have you considered using XSL for transforming your file? It's a much more common approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to modify the library itself, I don't see any way you can avoid doing a string replace.

Comment: This was basically what I had to do to get around this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SVG DOM API to set the viewBox:

```
$svg.each(function(index,node){
    node.viewBox.baseVal.x = 0
    node.viewBox.baseVal.y = 0
    node.viewBox.baseVal.width = 288
    node.viewBox.baseVal.height = 288
})
```

More info can be found in the SVG specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute

Comment: I noticed that jquery does not correctly report the updated svg property values when displaying the element from a selector, but the node itself will reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1):

What about if you get out of the jQuery object just for setting the attribute. e.g.

```
var $svg = $('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"></svg>');

$svg[0].setAttribute('viewBox', 0 + ' ' + 0 + ' ' + 288 + ' ' + 288);
```

Note: you may also want to check out this jQuery plugin: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html